# Laravel accessing user (coach) through request

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel and I have a problem creating a team with a coach's id using eloquent expressions. I have users (basic users who can become coaches), then I have coaches who can have only one team and lastly teams, which can have 1 or 2 coaches. Their tables:

```
Users:
id | email | password | coach_id (null is default)
Coaches:
id | user_id | ... (other unnecessary coach info)
Teams:
id | coach_id | ... (other unnecessary team info)
```

I tried creating a team in TeamController's method (following laravel tutorial on Youtube https://youtu.be/z-1bdYTNWm8?t=6m50s):

```
$team = new Team();
$team->team_name = $team_name;
$team->organization = $organization;
$team->address = $address;
$request->user()->coach()->team()->save($team);
```

My user model:

```
public function coach(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Coach');
}
```

My coach model:

```
public function user(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function team(){
   return $this->hasOne('App\Team');
}
```

My team model:

```
public function coach(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Coach');
}
```

But i get this error:

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2450:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::team()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it as:

```
$team = new Team();
$team->team_name = $team_name;
$team->organization = $organization;
$team->address = $address;

$request->user()->coach->team()->save($team);
```

*Note - Remove the `()` from `coach`relation.*

**Update**

When you add parenthesis `()` it creates the query builder and you don't have any relation named `team` in `User` model, so Laravel throws the error.

But when you do `$request->user()->coach` it returns the object of `Coach` model and then you can query it by the relation name `team`.

Comment: Well, that did the work! However, can you please explain me why does it work that way ?

Comment: If i may, is this better access, or would it be better if I created a relation named `team` in `User` model ? Or is there any other much better way of doing this.

Comment: This is the best way. It has no downside. And this the recommended way of saving related models.